# How to handle Java class which has Class<?> to convert to JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

For this class

```
public class Data {
Map<String, Class<?>> dataTypes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
       .serializeNulls()
       .create();

Data d = new Data();
d.dataTypes.put("DateParameter", java.util.Date.class);

System.out.println("Data is " + gson.toJson(d));
```

Prints the following:

> Data is {"dataTypes":{"DateParameter":{"annotationType":null}}}

How do get the correct class type printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write your own [custom json de/serializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ) for the [`Class` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).  Try something like this:

```java
public static class ClassSerializer implements
    JsonSerializer<Class>, JsonDeserializer<Class> {
  public JsonElement serialize(Class klass, Type type, JsonSerializationContext ctx) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(klass.getCanonicalName());
  }
  public Class deserialize(JsonElement el, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) throws JsonParseException {
    try {
      return Class.forName(el.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
      throw new JsonParseException(cnfe);
    }
  }
}

// ...
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassSerializer())
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    .serializeNulls()
    .create();
  Data d = new Data();
  d.dataTypes.put("DateParameter", java.util.Date.class);
  gson.toJson(d); // => {"dataTypes":{"DateParameter":"java.util.Date"}}
```

Comment: Thank you @maerics.  That solved my problem.  Accepted your answer.